# Is there a simple way to transform this JSON back and forth?

Tags: javascript, json, postman

We are using Postman for our API testing. Some object we are getting back are very verbose and not easy to handle, so I want to create a helper method to make them a bit more concise. I know there are all kind of transformation libraries like [node-json-transform](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-json-transform), [selecttransform](https://selecttransform.github.io/site/), [jsontransforms](https://github.com/ColinEberhardt/json-transforms), etc., but unfortunately I can only use the [Postman Sandbox libraries](https://learning.getpostman.com/docs/postman/scripts/postman_sandbox_api_reference/) and vanilla JS.

I am looking for the simplest (least amount of [loc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Source_lines_of_code) and functions) way to transform this object:

```
var verbose = [
    {
        "Key": "Name",
        "Value": "John Doe",
        "Instance": 1
    },
    {
        "Key": "Age",
        "Value": "33",
        "Instance": 1
    },
    {
        "Key": "Child",
        "Value": "Jane",
        "Instance": 1
    },
    {
        "Key": "Child",
        "Value": "Rocky",
        "Instance": 2
    }];
```

into this:

```
var concise =  {
    "Name": "John Doe",
    "Age": "33",
    "Child": ["Jane", "Rocky"]
};
```

and back again into the verbose form.

I already tried the native way of foreach-ing over each object and adding properties/values to a new object, but it went ugly soon when I reached the multiple instance key/value pairs. I can imagine there is an easier way using map/reduce but I am unfamiliar with those methods.

Comment: "I can imagine there is an easier way using map/reduce but I am unfamiliar with those methods." - then familiarise yourself with them.

Comment: How do you distinguish `"foo": "bar"` from `"foo": ["bar"]`? Or do you assume you will never have the second version, and automatically promote a simple value to an array value once a key is seen to be multivalued?

Comment: @Amadan good question. Your premise is right: this will never happen and a simple value should automatically be promoted to an array if multivalued.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I assume all attributes are multivalued, then I reduce those that have length 1 to a simple value. This is a bit slower than the reverse approach, where you assume values are singlevalued and promote them to arrays when they prove otherwise, in order to respect the ordering imposed by `Instance`.

```
function makeConcise(verbose) {
  let concise = {};
  verbose.forEach(({Key, Value, Instance}) => {
    if (!concise[Key]) concise[Key] = [];
    concise[Key][Instance - 1] = Value;
  });
  Object.keys(concise).forEach(Key => {
    if (concise[Key].length == 1) concise[Key] = concise[Key][0];
  });
  return concise;
}
```

The reverse function is similarly simple:

```
function makeVerbose(concise) {
  let verbose = [];
  Object.keys(concise).forEach(Key => {
    if (Array.isArray(concise[Key])) {
      concise[Key].forEach((Value, index) => {
        verbose.push({Key, Value, Instance: index + 1});
      });
    } else {
      verbose.push({Key, Value: concise[Key], Instance: 1});
    }
  });
  return verbose;
}
```

Comment: I pick this one as the one that solves my case the best, because it is pretty short, clear to read for novice JS developers and the most generic (no hard-coded keys). Nonetheless, thanks everyone for spending your valuable time onto this problem (you'll get an upvote :-)).

Answer (score 2):

Based on how I've understood your question, you want to create key-value pairs from your `verbose` array of objects. However, if there are key clashes, then the values should be converted into an array.

With that in mind, you will have to:

1. Use `forEach` to loop through your array of objects.
2. If key does not clash, we simply create a new key-value pair
3. If key clashes, then it gets a bit tricky:

   - If key clashes and this is the first occurrence, we convert the value in the key-value pair into an array
   - If key clashes and this is not the first occurrence, we know we are looking at an array
   - Now we *definitely* has an array, so we push our value into it

See proof-of-concept below:

```js
var verbose = [{
    "Key": "Name",
    "Value": "John Doe",
    "Instance": 1
  },
  {
    "Key": "Age",
    "Value": "33",
    "Instance": 1
  },
  {
    "Key": "Child",
    "Value": "Jane",
    "Instance": 1
  },
  {
    "Key": "Child",
    "Value": "Rocky",
    "Instance": 2
  }];

var concise = {};
verbose.forEach(function(i) {
  var key = i['Key'];
  var value = i['Value'];
  
  // If item exists, we want to convert the value into an array of values
  if (key in concise) {
    var item = concise[key];
    
    // If it is not an array already, we convert it to an array
    if (!Array.isArray(item))
      item = [item];
      
    item.push(value);
    concise[key] = item;
  }
  
  // If item does not exist, we simply create a new key-value pair
  else {
    concise[key] = value;
  }
});
console.log(concise);
```

Comment: Doesn't this answer only half of the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can do:

```js
const verbose = [{"Key": "Name","Value": "John Doe","Instance": 1},{"Key": "Age","Value": "33","Instance": 1},{"Key": "Child","Value": "Jane","Instance": 1},{"Key": "Child","Value": "Rocky","Instance": 2}];
const concise = Object.values(verbose.reduce((a, {Key, Value}) => (Key === 'Child' ? a.childs[0].Child.push(Value) : a.keys.push({[Key]: Value}), a), {keys: [], childs: [{Child: []}]})).flat(1);

console.log(concise);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: @Amadan Updated my answer. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
const verbose = [{
    "Key": "Name",
    "Value": "John Doe",
    "Instance": 1
  },
  {
    "Key": "Age",
    "Value": "33",
    "Instance": 1
  },
  {
    "Key": "Child",
    "Value": "Jane",
    "Instance": 1
  },
  {
    "Key": "Child",
    "Value": "Rocky",
    "Instance": 2
  }
];
let concise = {};

verbose.forEach(item => {
  const values = Object.values(item)
  if (concise[values[0]])  concise = {...concise, [values[0]]: [concise[values[0]], values[1]]};
  else concise = {...concise, ...{[values[0]]: values[1]}}
})
```

Comment: You'd "win" the shortest notation price. Unfortunately, Postman does not support the `...` notation in `{...consise, [values[0]]:`

Answer (score 1):

Try this. I have written both conversion functions.
I see other answers only provide only verbose to concise requirement.

```js
let verbose = [{
    "Key": "Name",
    "Value": "John Doe",
    "Instance": 1
  },
  {
    "Key": "Age",
    "Value": "33",
    "Instance": 1
  },
  {
    "Key": "Child",
    "Value": "Jane",
    "Instance": 1
  },
  {
    "Key": "Child",
    "Value": "Rocky",
    "Instance": 2
  }
]

let concise = {
  "Name": "John Doe",
  "Age": "33",
  "Child": ["Jane", "Rocky"]
}

verboseToConcise = (verbose) => {
  let obj = {}
  verbose.forEach(v => {
    let key = obj[v.Key]
    if (key) typeof key === 'string' ? obj[v.Key] = [key, v.Value] : key.push(v.Value)
    else obj[v.Key] = v.Value
  })
  return obj
}

conciseToVerbose = (concise) => {
  let arr = []
  Object.entries(concise).forEach(([key, value]) => {
    if (typeof value === 'object') {
      for (let i = 0; i < value.length; i++){
        arr.push({
          "Key": key,
          "Value": value[i],
          "Instance": i+1
        })
      }
    } else {
      arr.push({
        "Key": key,
        "Value": value,
        "Instance": 1
      })
    }
  })
  return arr
}

console.log(verboseToConcise(verbose))
console.log(conciseToVerbose(concise))
```

Answer (score 1):

I also gave it a try using `reduce`:

EDIT: Without `...` spread syntax, with `Object.assign` and `array.concat`

EDIT2: I wanted to try and turn it back again. In this code we lose the value of `Instance`:(

```
var verbose = [
  {
    Key: 'Name',
    Value: 'John Doe',
    Instance: 1,
  },
  {
    Key: 'Age',
    Value: '33',
    Instance: 1,
  },
  {
    Key: 'Child',
    Value: 'Jane',
    Instance: 1,
  },
  {
    Key: 'Child',
    Value: 'Rocky',
    Instance: 2,
  },
]

const concise = verbose.reduce(
  (p, n) =>
    Object.assign(p, {
      [n.Key]: !p.hasOwnProperty(n.Key)
        ? n.Value
        : typeof p[n.Key] === 'string'
        ? [p[n.Key], n.Value]
        : p[n.Key].concat(n.Value),
    }),
  {},
)

console.log(concise)
// { Name: 'John Doe', Age: '33', Child: [ 'Jane', 'Rocky' ] }

const backAgain = Object.entries(concise).reduce(
  (p, [k, v]) =>
    Array.isArray(v)
      ? p.concat(v.map(x => ({ Key: k, Value: x })))
      : p.concat({ Key: k, Value: v }),
  [],
)

console.log(backAgain)
// [ { Key: 'Name', Value: 'John Doe' },
//  { Key: 'Age', Value: '33' },
//  { Key: 'Child', Value: 'Jane' },
//  { Key: 'Child', Value: 'Rocky' } ]
```

Comment: Unfortunately, Postman does not support the `...` notation in `{...,[n,Key]:`

Comment: Thank you, I update with `Object.assign` and `array.concat` syntax.